# Implementing MVC observer pattern with google guice

Tags: java, model-view-controller, guice, observer-pattern

I have a good understanding of mvc. What Im still unsure about is how to properly use google guice to inject dependencies. Here is part of my code:

```
protected void configure() {
    bind(IAppController.class).to(AppController.class);
    bind(IAppView.class).to(AppView.class);
    bind(IAppModel.class).to(AppModel.class);
}
```

Now, I am unsure how to inject the dependencies properly. I would like to ask your opinion on the best way to handle this. I Inject them in the constructors like this

```
public class AppController implements IAppController {

private IAppView appView;
private IAppModel appModel;

@Inject
public AppController(IAppView appView, IAppModel appModel){
    this.appModel = appModel;
    this.appView = appView;
}
```

}

Now the example above works but adds another problem. How can i give the model an instance of the view? My view is the observer and i need the same instance of the injected view in the controller to be injected in the model. Another approach I came up with is to simply use the injector to get instances of the model, view, controller and assemble them there? such as:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new AppBootstrapLoader());
    IAppController controller = injector.getInstance(IAppController.class);
    IAppView view =...
    IAppModel model =....
    controller.setModel(model);
    controller.setView(view);
    model.addObserver(view);
}
```

My last approach would be to have the model view and controller as singletons so I would be sure that all injected instances are the same. Im still new to guice and I still cant comprehend how it handles dependencies. I also want to do this cleanly and thus I am researching. I would like to hear your experiences and opinions on this manner. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is *"method injection."* Note that the binding process will fail if the given dependency dose not exist.

*Method Injection:*

```
@Inject
public void setView(View view) {
    this.view = view;
}
```

You could also use field injection. But I'm not really a fan of it because it makes writing unit tests harder if you can only set the dependency through reflection.

*Field Injection:*

```
@Inject
private View view
```

source: [injections](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Injections)

Comment: I have read about that. Now I cant find enough resources to ensure that when I create instances of the model view and controller they will assemble properly. What i mean is will the model receive the same instance of view that the controller received. Sorry just started guice

Comment: It sounds like you want to declare your instances as singletons. This can be done through your module (when building the bindings) or by using the @Singleton annotation. See Scopes: https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Scopes

Comment: If i do not add the @Singleton annotation how will guice handle dependency injection?

Comment: It creates a new instance every time the binding is requested.

Comment: Thank you. In your opinion, is my approach correct in using guice with MVC?

Comment: It's correct (as in it works), but I don't like it from a DI standpoint. You shouldn't be setting the dependencies directly, at least not at the root of your application.

Comment: Im not that experienced with DI. What do you mean by "You shouldn't be setting the dependencies directly, at least not at the root of your application". I thought you bind them in the configure method using guice?

Comment: I'm talking about your last example in your question. Using "setModel" is setting the dependency directly. If you use the method injectors and singletons, i think it'll look good.

Comment: Thanks! You were a big help. I tend to stress a lot on the design phase specially when Im using something new. Im not all that knowledgeable on properly implementing DI.